# incrementing the value of child in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase details photo]

My app is a monthly basis app. like every 1st of the month my app should do the calculations and update the data in firebase.. as there is no function like that I'm using a button(reset) on which when clicked do the calculations and update in Firebase but I don't know how to update all date child in all nodes please help me.

Till now I have tried this.

```
datarefoutstd = database.getReference("outstdln");

datarefoutstd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot outsnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            outsnapshot.child("date").setValue(snapshot.getValue(Long.class)+1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment by one the value of the `date` property within all nodes, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference outstdlnRef = db.child("outstdln");
outstdlnRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.child("date").getRef().setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

This code will work only if you **change the type of the `date` property from String to a number**. It's really a bad practice to store numbers as strings. You should always store the data according to its correct data type.

Comment: Thank you so much for information.. and would you mind helping some more actually I was hoping that someone would tell me the general answer like the increment value would be our choice to the date of different nodes.. would you please help me to get the value of stdln and calculate stdln/100 and update that value in stdin.. please help me

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. As a personal opinion, there isn't a general answer. If you need to do more calculations, then please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: ok..done by the way thank you for your help